# How to know if Data in inserted or not in the Database using Laravel 8 Eloquent method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am create a page in that a product is uploaded and its create a relationship with category table. Everything is working fine but I am not able to know if the data is inserted or not.

```
Product::create([
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'title' => $request->input('title'),
                'slug' => $request->input('title'),
                'description' => $request->input('description'),
                'tags' => $request->input('tags'),
                'type' => $request->input('type'),
                'category' => $request->input('category'),
                'doc_file' => $fileName,
                'file_location' => $firebase_storage_path,
                'status' => '0',
                'added_by' => Cookie::get('admin_id')
            ])->categories()->attach($request->input('category'));
```

Comment: [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_attach) seems to return `void` while [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_sync) seems to return `array`

Comment: attach() used to create a relationship between tables [category and product]

Comment: I know. Sync also does that. The difference is, that sync also does `detach()` if necessary.

Comment: attach is only used in a Many-Many relationship

Comment: Thanks Everyone sync() do the job